# CTCarrier returning nil on all properties

Tags: ios, swift, core-telephony

I'm making use of the following code to obtain the `mobileNetworkCode`:

```
let ctCarrier = CTCarrier()

    func getMNC() -> String {
        if let mnc = ctCarrier.mobileNetworkCode {
            return mnc
        }
        return "nil"
    }
```

Using any properties of CTCarrier returns nil and seems like a bug from Apple.

Any workaround as to this problem?

Comment: Did you get any solution to this problem ??

Answer (score 3):

```
let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
let carrier = networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider
let mobileNetworkCode = carrier!.mobileNetworkCode

if mobileNetworkCode != nil {
    //Means got reception
} else {
   //No cellular data
}
```

Please try this way, i also test using `CTCarrier()` directly, it always returns nil. This method works.

Comment: Looks like Apple forgot to make the CTCarrier initializer private...

Comment: having the same issue, getting `nil` on all of `CTCarrier` properties. Makes me wonder if Im missing any capability I should add?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following:

1. You're using a real device when debugging.
2. It has a sim card.
3. Device has a signal.
4. Not on Airplane Mode.

Discussion on **mobileNetworkCode**:

> A read-only NSString object that represents the numeric mobile network
>   code for the user’s cellular service provider. Typing this property as
>   an NSString object, rather than a number type, ensures that leading
>   zeroes in MNCs are respected.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/ctcarrier/1620324-mobilenetworkcode

Comment: All of the above are true:
1. iPhone 7+
2. Active SIM
3. Device has reception
4. Airplane Mode Inactive

Comment: Facing same issue. is there any workaround of this issue ??

Comment: having the same issue, getting `nil` on all of `CTCarrier` properties. Makes me wonder if Im missing any capability I should add?